# Paint method in java

Tags: java, graphics

I want to ask about the Paint method in java when i execute my code the Paint method gets called.

So how to stop the paint method?

note: I made a button to do the paint method.

Usually when i execute the code the Paint method gets called by default .. so i need to stop it and make my button when i click on it , calls the Paint method.

here the code

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandDraw extends JApplet  implements ActionListener {

JButton Draw1 = new JButton ("Draw");

public void init() {
  this.setLayout (new FlowLayout());
  this.add(Draw1);
  Draw1.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  if(e.getSource()==Draw1)
    repaint();
  }
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
  for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
    g.setColor
      (new Color(i*655%256,i*355%256,i*958%256));
    Random r = new Random ();
    int rr= r.nextInt(40)+10;
    Random r1 = new Random ();
    int rr1= r1.nextInt(70)+10;
    Random r2 = new Random ();
    int rr2= r2.nextInt(10)+10;
    g.fillOval(2*rr1,rr*rr2,O+O1*2,O+O1*2);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You have to give us a bit more information about what you're specifically trying to do. Are you using Swing? Usually paint methods only get called when there's a reason for them to be redrawn. Do you have any code in your paint method which might cause your program to run in an endless loop or block / freeze?

Comment: Don't click the button???  Question is not clear to me...

Comment: It stops after the code has completed...

Comment: i did not use Swing
Usually when i execute the code the Paint method gets called by default .. so i need to stop it and make my button when i click on it , calls the Paint method..

Comment: this doesn't sound like a good way to solve your problem. Tell us a little more about what you're trying to do and maybe we can offer an alternative.

Comment: Did you know you can reuse random generators and get a second, new random value out of them? Drop all your `new Random`, one is enough.

Comment: aha thank you for informing me....

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a `boolean` member variable `doDraw` to your class. Mark it as `volatile.`
2. In the `ActionListener` for the button, toggle the value of `doDraw`. If it's true, make it false; if it's false, make it true.
3. Finally, enclose the body of your `paint()` method with

   if (doDraw) {
       // Rest of the code here
   }

And there you go!

Comment: and drop all your `new Random()`. One random number *generator* (it can generate more than one number) should be enough for you. That's why the method is called `nextInt` btw, because it will not return the previous one again...

Comment: +1 for adding a boolean property to control painting. -1, for encouraging the overriding of the paint() method (especially in a top level container). Custom painting should be done by overding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then add the panel to the applet.

Comment: Heh. Laziness on my part; just wanted to answer the question, not teach him how to fish.

Comment: -1 if you can't answer a question properly then why answer the question? Now others, have to take the time to try to teach the poster how to do it properly so they don't get into bad habits. Or worse yet other people who search and find this posting might think the original code is valid and will copy it. That is how all the bad code gets circulated around the web and we end up correcting it over and over rather than doing it correct the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should override paintComponent(), which eventually gets called by paint().  Do any of your fancy stuff in paintComponent().

Not sure I understand the rest of your question - see Ernest's response.